# Crear filtro php con query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estimados no logro que mi consulta muestre los filtros correctamente:

```
select `valores`.*, `comprobante`.* from `valores` 
 inner join `comprobante` on `valores`.`iditem` = `comprobante`.`iditem` 
 where Estados LIKE 'Pagados%' 
 OR Lcodido LIKE 'TR %' 
 OR Lcodido LIKE 'DG %' 
 ORDER BY FALTAFW DESC
```

Quiero como resultado que me muestre los codigos de Lcodido, pero unicamente los que esten Pagados.El filtro funciona con un solo Lcodigo, cuando lo coloco dos como muestra query me muestra todos estados, pagados y no pagados.. como puedo hacer para me muestre los estados pagados con mas de un Lcodigo.

Comment: Esto es sql.. el orden de los factores altera el producto.. vos estas escribiendo que el estado sea pagado **O** Lcodigo sea TR **O** Lcodigo sea DG... se entiende?

Comment: @gbianchi un `WHERE IN` con los 2 `LCodigo` y al final un `WHERE` con `Estados`? con un `AND` en medio?

Comment: eso suena mucho mejor @Aprendiz

Comment: me podrian pasar un ejemplo de la consulta?

Comment: Como te comentó @gbianchi el problema es cómo estás usando el OR: actualmente dice "traeme los datos si Estados se parece a 'Pagados%' o Lcodido se parece a 'TR %' o Lcodido se parece a 'DG %'. Por lo que explicas en tu pregunta debería ser algo como "Traeme los datos cuando Estados se parece a 'Pagados%' Y (Lcodido se parece a 'TR %' o Lcodido se parece a 'DG %'), o algo así...

Answer (score 0):

**Solo es cosa de poner un paréntesis entre los Lcodido, para que te busco uno u otro, y un AND en estados para que solo muestre los Pagados, quedaría algo así:**

```
select `valores`.*, `comprobante`.* from `valores` 
inner join `comprobante` on `valores`.`iditem` = `comprobante`.`iditem` 
where ( Lcodido LIKE 'TR %' OR Lcodido LIKE 'DG %' )
AND Estados LIKE 'Pagados%'
```